# Where to find others with Prusa3D i3m3s/MMU2s printer?

Tags: discussion

I don't want to ask off-topic and opinion questions here, but I would like to find a cadre of others dialing in their devices.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try Facebook groups. For example: https://www.facebook.com/groups/prusacommunity/

Comment: HI, I migrated the question to meta, I hope that you understand why. :-) BTW, What do you mean by `dialing in their devices` exactly? Do you mean comparing their printers and posting pix? Or something else? @Starwind has a (large?) Facebook group, he might know more...? I don't have a Facebook account (left it years ago) so I don't know anything about that...

Comment: I thought I had written it on meta.  I wonder what I did wrong?   It is totally not a main group question.

Comment: @greenline I'm not sure what word is used in the Prusa community.  I mean going through the process of tweaking this and that to improve the reliability. There is data in support of the mmu2 being a great addition, but at the moment I have a user interaction rate of about 5-7%.  With 100 changes, I have to intervene on about 6 of them.

Comment: @Mick Thanks for the reference to the Facebook group.  I'm waiting for a moderator to approve my join request.

Comment: Ah *tweaking*, now that's a word I can understand... gotcha :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled across this forum/group, [Original Prusa i3 MMU2S & MMU2](https://forum.prusaprinters.org/forum/english-forum-original-prusa-i3-mmu2s-mmu2/), amongst all of the other [Prusa printers forums](https://forum.prusaprinters.org) on the [Prusaprinters blog](https://blog.prusaprinters.org/prusa-i3/), which seems fairly active.

In particular, the [User mods - OctoPrint, enclosures, nozzles, ...](https://forum.prusaprinters.org/forum/original-prusa-i3-mmu2s-mmu2-user-mods-octoprint-enclosures-nozzles-.../) page seems like it might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of activity on Reddit related to 3D printing and the Prusa printers.